# JavaScript class to populate object

Tags: javascript

I am trying to populate an object by using a JavaScript class. I am not even sure if I am doing it correctly, I am very new to JavaScript OOP.

```
var ImagesViewModel = {}; // Global object

function ImagesClass() {

    this.addImage = function (iUrl) {
        ImagesViewModel.push({ "ImageUrl": iUrl }) //<  Error is here
    }

}

var k = new ImagesClass()
k.addImage("http://www.yahoo.com")
k.addImage("http://www.xbox.com")
```

Basically I need an easy way to populate `ImagesViewModel` with multiple properties. Do I need to specify properties within `ImagesViewModel`? Maybe I can do all of this without having to specify a global variable?

I am getting the error

> Object has no method PUSH

Comment: That's just an object – not JSON.

Comment: Please note that the problem has **nothing** to do with JSON at all. It seems you are confusing JavaScript object literals (constructs of the JavaScript language syntax) with JSON (a language-independent data-exchange format, like XML or CSV). I will edit your question accordingly. See also: [There is no such thing as a "JSON object"](http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you want is an array and not an object, push is a method on Array prototype and you are trying to use it on object.

Change:

```
var ImagesViewModel = {};
```

To:

```
var ImagesViewModel = [];
```

You can do it this way as well so that each instance of `ImagesClass` has its own set of images.

```
function ImagesClass() {
    var  _images = [];

    this.addImage = function (iUrl) {
       _images.push({ "ImageUrl": iUrl }) //<  Error is here
    }

    this.getImages = function(){
      return _images;
    }
}
```

and use it as:

```
var k = new ImagesClass();
k.addImage("http://www.yahoo.com");
k.addImage("http://www.xbox.com");
var ImagesViewModel = k.getImages(); //You can either set it directly or as a property of object
console.log(ImagesViewModel);
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/fckwn/)**

Comment: Got it, in my example above, can i do everything within the CLASS instead of having to declare a global variable?

Comment: @highwingers You can, just move the variable inside the class.

Answer (score 1):

the push method is only for Arrays, here you are trying to push() to an object, which is why it isn't working.

You will need to change `var ImagesViewModel = {};` to `var ImagesViewModel = [];`

Answer (score 1):

From a design perspective, you probably don't want your viewmodel to just be a flat array (even though you declared it as an object, as other posters pointed out).

I'd suggest declaring an array declaration to hold the images inside of your ImagesViewModel object.

```
var ImagesViewModel = { // ViewModel generic OBJECT
  this.Images = new Array(); // prototype ARRAY object
}; 

function ImagesClass() {    
    this.addImage = function (iUrl) {    
        ImagesViewModel.Images.push({ "ImageUrl": iUrl }) 
    }

}
```